# compile a program using static library from command line

Tags: c, visual-c++

Ok I created a simple static library, myLib.lib, now in my program I make:

```
#include "mylib.h"

void somefun(){
       call a lib fun
}
```

I compile with

> cl myFile.c /link myLib.lib

but it gives me:

> Cannot open included file "mylib.h" no such a file or directory

why?

Comment: Where is your "mylib.h"? Is it in the same directory? Or somewhere else? You probably need to add the directory where "mylib.h" lies to your Include path.

Comment: thanks it worked! if you write it as answer I'll mark you as right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the location of `mylib.h` to your include path. Otherwise your library can't find it. Use the [`/I` flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx):

```
cl myFile.c /I ..\mylib\ /link myLib.lib
```

*Note*: Code is not tested, but should work like this.